# Laptop getting too hot after installing kubuntu-desktop in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, kubuntu, overheating

I installed kubuntu-desktop 2 days ago and now my laptop is getting very very hot within 15 minutes even if i only run my browser.

This problem remains even when i log in to unity. I have been using ubuntu for a few months using unity and there was no such problem.

Is installing multiple desktop environments bad for my laptop?

Also whenever i shutdown or start my computer i get something like this in a black screen for a second or two :

**timeout in write_ec_cmd**

*I am dual booting ubuntu with windows 10 and there is no overheating problem when i use windows 10*

Comment: Open the "System monitor" utility, or run `top` in a terminal, and see if anything is using a high percentage of CPU resources.

Comment: Is your fan working? If you are not sure, you can try install sensors to detect fan speed, there are many set-up guides out there. However, if your computer do not have a hardware sensor, there are no software that can help.

Comment: @PyGeek03 I installed lm-sensors and ran sensors. It showed me my CPU temperatures and it was very hot (averaging about 72C, occassionally reaching 80C). But it doesn't show my fan speed. If i put my ear close to the vent i can hear it running, but still laptop is very hot.

Comment: @JonasCz Using System monitor i found out that one app  (mail-notification) that autostarts when i log in takes a lot of my CPU (~50%). I uninstalled it and the temperature came down a bit, but still is very hot (~70C) even at 20% CPU usage. Is it normal?

Comment: What else is using that 20% CPU ? CPU usage should be 0, or close to 0 when idle.  I don't think that's normal though, no.

Comment: @SK Well if you can hear it running then the fan is not the problem. The reason for no fan speed is that your hardware doesn't support that feature.

Comment: @JonasCz When i last checked there was firefox, psensor, compiz. They usually are taking less than 15% combined. Should i uninstall kubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @SK Sorry for the late reply, have you tried using kwin instead of compiz?